# Yocto recipe to manage Go dependencies with dep tool

Tags: go, dependencies, yocto, recipe

Update: This question is already SOLVED. I'm re-editing the question to update to the fixed state.

I'm trying to write a recipe that uses `dep` tool to resolve dependencies of a `go` related project before building it. I'm using the 'poky' layer of the 'rocko' Yocto project branch. That branch provides recipes to build  the `go` compiler and the `dep` dependencies tool.

My initial recipe fetches source code from a bitbucket repository:

```
GO_IMPORT = "bitbucket.org/path/to/my_project"
SRC_URI = "git://${GO_IMPORT}/protocol=http;user=${GIT_USER}:${GIT_PASS};destsuffix=${PN}-${PV}/src/${GO_IMPORT}"
```

Then I add this:

```
inherit go
DEPENDS += "go-dep"
```

And after I add this function:

```
do_compile_prepend() {
    dep init
    dep ensure
}
```

Yocto complains with this error:

```
run.do_compile.8543: line 118: dep: command not found
```

After reading some of your answers below, I add suggested patch in your answers at the end of my poky/meta/recipes-devtools/go/go-dep_0.3.0.bb recipe file - thanks a lot!! :-)

```
BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"
```

After I execute some bitbake commands:

```
$ bitbake -c cleanall go-dep-native
$ bitbake go-dep-native
```

Bitbake process ends ok, displaying no errors nor warnings. The native `go-dep` tool has been built into tmp/work/x86_64-linux/go-dep-native directory and is properly installed into tmp/sysroots-components/x86_64/go-dep-native/usr/bin.

I modify the do_compile_prepend() function as shown below:

```
do_compile_prepend() {
    rm -f ${WORKDIR}/build/src/${GO_IMPORT}/Gopkg.toml
    rm -f ${WORKDIR}/build/src/${GO_IMPORT}/Gopkg.lock
    cd ${WORKDIR}/build/src/${GO_IMPORT}
    dep init
    dep ensure
}
```

I modify DEPENDS in my recipe like this:

```
DEPENDS = "go-native go-dep-native"
```

Note the go-dep has been removed (I don't need `dep` tool on the target device, just to resolve dependencies on the native platform).

After that, I execute this command:

```
$ bitbake <foo>
```

The do_compile stage works fine, but some errors appear when doing the do_package stage:

```
ERROR: <foo>-1.0-r0 do_package: QA Issue: File '/usr/bin/dep' from <foo> was already stripped, this will prevent future debugging! [already-stripped]
ERROR: <foo>-1.0-r0 do_package: Fatal QA errors found, failing task.
ERROR: <foo>-1.0-r0 do_package: Function failed: do_package
```

These errors are fixed appending this at the end of my recipe:

```
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_DEBUG_SPLIT = "1"
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1"
RDEPENDS_${PN}-staticdev += "bash"
RDEPENDS_${PN}-dev += "bash"
```

I don't know if this is the best way to solve my issue, but at least now it works fine. Any advice to improve this recipe is wellcome. Thank you in advance! :-)

Comment: I'm not familiar with yocto but usually with go-dep (or go commands in general) when they are obtained by a `go get github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep` command the executable `dep` command will go into the $GOPATH/bin directory so I think that you need to add $GOPATH/bin to your PATH environment variable so the command can be found.

Comment: Or if you can't change the PATH variable you could always change the do_compile_prepend to `$GOPATH/bin/dep init`

Answer (score 4):

The `DEPENDS += "go-dep"` means that your *target* recipe can include headers or link libs provided by go-dep, but you can't run the dep command, if you need run dep command, you need depend on go-dep-native:

```
DEPENDS += "go-dep-native"
```

But yocto doesn't provide go-dep-native currently, so you have to add:

```
BBCLASSEXTEND = "native"
```

to `meta/recipes-devtools/go/go-dep_XXX.bb.`

Then you can run dep command in `do_compile_prepend()`

Answer (score 2):

I just sent the patch[1] to enable the native and nativesdk support for the recipe.

1. https://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/147390/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, [it is better](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231) to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the same recipe as the one [here](http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/go/go-dep_0.3.1.bb?h=master), you should be able to refer to the ${GO_INSTALL} variable in your do_compile_prepend build step. If not, try running -c devshell with your bitbake command, like:

```
bitbake <package name> -c devshell
```

and look for the path of the dep tool.

Comment: I think that will just point to the code in the /cmd/dep package not the installed command itself. Looking at what it inherits it's the `${GOBIN}` path that is actually required from here:
http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/go/go-target.inc
So the command should be:

do_compile_prepend() {
    ${GOBIN}/dep init
}